# Failed Dependency "Web Server Administration module" during Axapta Setup

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, axapta, windows-server-2012-r2

Im trying to install AX 2012 Async server on a machine with 
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
IIS:8.5

One of the prerequisites gives me the following error as shown in the screenshot

[image: AX async server - Web administration module error]

I have installed the script with the command `Import-Module C:\"Path to Module" -Verbose` (as mentioned in the above image), however still the prerequisite persists I have tried restarting the server. But to no avail.

This is the screenshot of running the command:

[image: Import module command output]

I think the command is not being run successfully , The alternative version of the command `AddPSSnapin` throws an error. What seems to be the issue here?

EDIT: This is the log file prerequisite check:

```
2016-02-15 16:17:25Z   Performing a check for pre-requisite 'Web Server (IIS) Administration module'.
2016-02-15 16:17:29Z    Check if WebAdministration module is available
2016-02-15 16:17:29Z    No
2016-02-15 16:17:29Z    Trying to add snapin for older version of Windows.
2016-02-15 16:17:29Z    Unable to import web administration module or snapin. Please install the IIS web administration module or snapin for PowerShell
```

AS shown here it seems to be trying to add snapin and then failing the prerequisite.

Comment: Go into Add Roles and ensure that  `Web Server (IIS) > Management Tools > IIS Management Scripts and Tools` is installed

Comment: I just checked that, it was not installed , Im adding it now , however while trying to correcting this issue i remember removing the management tools and reinstalling them, I must have left this out by mistake. Ill run the command again and tell you if anything changes now. 
EDIT: It's installed now and still the prerequisite is showing as the image above,

Comment: if you import the module manually into PowerShell can you do `cd IIS:` to get to the IIS drive?

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand you, You mean after running the command on powershell? I tried the command and yes, i can get into the IIS drive.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. That suggests WebAdministration is importing (at least partially but I would be surprised if there were problems with it). It's odd, Import-Module only affects the current session (not installing, just loading) - are you launching the AX setup through PowerShell?

Comment: No, I am not launching the AX setup through powershell.

Comment: Does `Get-Module -ListAvailable` list the web administration module? Can you import the module using just the module name, *not* the full path?

Comment: One of the anomaly i can see here is that the powershell version is showing up as 2.0 in the prerequisites check(as shown in the 1'st screenshot), however the path to import-module command is showing v1.0. Could this be causing the unexpected issue??

Comment: Ansgar, the Get-Module -ListAvailable command doesn't list the Web Administration module. And i cannot import it directly , it throws an error:"No valid module was found in any module directory".

Comment: Check the value of `$env:PSModulePath`. It should show ``C:\Users\<your_account>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\``.

Comment: Just to address abhinavm93, that is the language version of PowerShell. That is to say, a script written in PS 2.0 will still work for PS 4.0. A new language version is one that would "break" existing scripts (.ps1 files) so we would move to v2 language and .ps2 files, but keep the old v1 for compatibility of old scripts.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you! That was the solution , I set the PSMODULE path C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modul‌​es\  and used the import - module command again , the prerequisite check completed successfully! But shouldn't it import with the complete path too? Where was the exact problem. Can you explain Ansgar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the `PSModulePath` system environment variable doesn't seem to be set on your server. Because of that you can load the module when you specify its full path, but not when you specify just the name (`Import-Module WebAdministration`). The prerequisites check of the installer most likely checks the presence of the module by name as well, since `$env:PSModulePath` usually contains more than one location, and it shouldn't matter which of them actually contains the module.

Set the system environment variable `PSModulePath` to `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modul‌​es` and the problem should disappear.